# If I have two iframes on a page, is it possible to transfer a MessageChannel originating in one to another?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have two iframes on my page and want to send messages between them, can I create a message channel in one and send a port it to the other (by way of a mediator script on the host)?

```
<body>
  <iframe src="https://example.com/a" />
  <iframe src="https://example.com/b" />
</body>
```

EDIT:

Or are there better alternatives, for example using the mediator script on the host as a message broker, or perhaps creating the MessageChannel in the host and passing the two ports down?

Comment: so what is sending the message? `a -> parent -> b` or just `parent -> a & b`

Comment: `a <--> b` is the goal

Comment: so you would need the parent to handle the conversations. between the two since a and b have no relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, just make the parent document transfer it appropriately:

```js
const channel = new MessageChannel();
frameA.contentWindow.postMessage('', '*', [channel.port1]);
frameB.contentWindow.postMessage('', '*', [channel.port2]);
```

And then in each frame you'll grab the ports and communicate directly between frameA and frameB.

Where the MessageChannel is created doesn't matter, ports are transferred.

Since StackSnippets overly protected iframes don't let us do anything with inner frames [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tsxwz1a/).