# postMessage through multiple unfriendly Iframes

Tags: javascript

I have three different domains (DomainA.com,DomainB.com,DomainC.com).

[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nlDR.png)

I tried to send a postMessage from domainC to domainA with in the following ways:

```
window.parent.postMessage('foo','https://domainA') // this sends it just to the parent which works fine
```

I also tried window.frames hoping to send messages to all frames

```
window.frames.postMessage('foo','https://domainA') // or
window.frames.postMessage('foo','*')
```

While debugging I saw that window.frames shows length 0 when executed on domainC. Is that usable at all to work with the parent Iframes?

What ways could I use to communicate from domain C to domain A?

Comment: You mean like in this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57958599/if-i-have-two-iframes-on-a-page-is-it-possible-to-transfer-a-messagechannel-ori/57958903#57958903)?